# How to upload file on my google drive public folder from my app's user side?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I have made a simple puzzle game in android. I want the top scorers to be displayed on a web page hosted on my google drive's public folder. 
i.e when the user completes the game his score should be posted on the drive and the list on the drive should be updated.

```
(Is it possible)? How : Any alternative;
```

thank you.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: nothing, I have no Idea on google drive. Just finished the app and finding a way to show synchronized top scorers list.

Answer (score 1):

To allow uploads to your Google drive folder you would have to include your Google password in your App so **don't do it!**  as you will be giving access to **all** your Google stuff away.

Better to set up an email box that it automatically, ***with the users permission***, mails to.  You can then automatically or periodically distil a high scores page from the inbox of that account.

You could also set up a web page with a POST method that your program automatically has access to because it has the login details **for that page only**.  Again don't forget to get the users permission.

The user permissions are important because:

1. You are using their account to post information which may incur charges
2. You are posting some information about them
3. If their boss sees the high score rising while they are supposed to be working...

Comment: @Steve.. which is the better way from your point of view?

Comment: Both have advantages - the web page would update immediately but the email solution is probably easier and less vulnerable.

Comment: @Steve..I havn't done much work in http Post/get. so Can you please illustrate (with small code) how can I provide login details for a page. And post/update data on it. or send me a link.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP) would be a starting point.